# Get undefined callback

Tags: javascript, csv, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have code like this when I console log the fileContent is gives correct output but when I try to get it as a return it gives error.

I want to use the contents of csv file in other functions.While keeping code clean.

```
    ;(function(){

    function readTextFile(file)
    {
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
var fileContent;
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
           fileContent =csvJSON(allText);
           return fileContent;
        }
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
    }


    function csvJSON(csv){
    var lines=csv.split("\n");

    var result = [];

    var headers=lines[0].split(",");

    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

    var obj = {};
var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
  obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
}

result.push(obj);

    }

    return result; //JavaScript object
    //return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
    }

    var mainContent = readTextFile("main.csv");


    })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know a little about asynchronous work. When you set handler to `readystatechange` you just subscribing to that event from XMLHttpRequest, your function will be called when this event is fire. Therefore this function can not return something back to you. Except if you specify another function called `callback` and in handler after all call it.

Look at this:

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    var fileContent;
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
               fileContent =csvJSON(allText);
               callback(fileContent);
            }
        }
    }
```

And when you want request:

```
readTextFile('main.csv', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

This is how asynchronous calculation work.